# What's the current status of Searle's Chinese Room argument?

Tags: john-searle

The purpose of my question is not to start an endless discussion on Searle's thought experiment, but just to ask if the argument still stands or if at some point in time it was effectively shown to be flawed and dismissed forever. References will be helpful.

Comment: A good guide to counter-arguments can be found in the "Replies to the Chinese Room Argument" section of the [Stanford Encyclopedia entry on it](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/chinese-room/). But like most issues in philosophy there is no consensus on whether the counter-arguments have disposed of it or not--most advocates of [computational theories of mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_theory_of_mind) probably think one or another of them is sufficient to show that the Chinese Room poses no problem for computationalism, while many non-computationalists would not.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Thanks, that reference sums it up nicely:  "...Despite the extensive discussion there is still no consensus...". I think the argument is fundamentally flawed, but then again I have not read all there is to it and that's why I'm asking, just curious as to why it has lasted so long.